# How to access to a a HTML video functions from an Angular custom directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm tyring to write an own custom directive for HTML `video` element, I got this:

```
finalCutApp.directive('finalcutPlayer', ($timeout) => {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: ($scope, $elem, $attrs) => {
            $elem.on('canplay', () => {
                $timeout(()=> {$scope.$emit('finalcutplayer.events.canplay')});
            });
        }
    };
});
```

So I got this markup:

```
  <video finalcut-player id="html5-player" controls>
    <source src="videos/react@iugh.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

So far I've achieved to get the event catched up at my controller. However I'm not sure how I can either programatically start the player or even change and reload its sources.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: check this link  http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngVideo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$elem` is Jquery object. You can access method and properties like this:

```
$elem[0].play();
```

Here's [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/UqMWPwQcXvwWHdAN2vn1).